# What does "[Syntax Error]: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_AND, got '00'" error in Symfony2 mean?

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create query:

```
$od = '2015-04-13 00:00:00';
$do = '2015-05-01 00:00:00';
$query = 'date BETWEEN '.$od.' AND '.$do;
```

and got error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 111: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_AND, got '00'
```

Symfony2 debug logs:

```
QueryException: SELECT z 
FROM AppBundle:Zamowienie z 
WHERE z.datazlozenia BETWEEN 2015-04-13 00:00:00 AND 2015-05-01 00:00:00 
ORDER BY z.idzamowienie ASC
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to put the dates under quotes to provide a correct syntax of the query:

```
$query = "date between '" . $od . "' AND '" . $do . "'";
```

Better look into using prepared statements and replacing query arguments instead of concatenating queries, as it tends to open up SQL-injection attacks.

Comment: prepare statements in doctrine mean using `->setParameter`?

Comment: Yes it is. For example in a repository $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($query)->setParameter("od", $od)->setParameter("do", $do); And your query string will be like this : $query = "date between :od AND :do "; (of course with a SELECT statement, FROM statement, ...)